# How to set new spellchecker language in Pidgin?

Tags: pidgin, spell-checking

I'm using Pidgin and I'm using en_US as default Ubuntu language . But I want to use pt_PT as default spellchecker on Pidgin. How I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After one month of search I found [here](http://linuxblog.darkduck.com/2014/06/how-to-enable-spell-check-in-pidgin-linux.html) the solution:

Navigate to your package manager and select the package **pidgin-plugin-pack**.

Once installed, go to Pidgin and select menu `Tools – Plugins` and activate the **Switch Spell** plugin there. This plugin will place an additional menu section on the Pidgin messaging window that allows you to select language for each particular conversation.

Comment: The plugin pack adds various new options,  but the 'change spell' plugin adds nothing new and is redundant. - At least in version 1.10.12:  any new buddy will always have the system language spellchecker enabled by default; that fact cannot be changed, but *for each buddy* a different  language can be set by right-click in the input area (and it will be remembered after restart, therefore will be "default" for that buddy).

Comment: @user000001 - not really: just right-click the typing area, no new plugin needed

Comment: FWIW the default spellchecker does *not* remember the language for me for next time. However, using the Switch Spell plugin works. N.B. you need to use the menu at the top of the conversation window to select language; right-clicking the input area won't persist.